# Como usar o login do Facebook na plataforma universal do Windows?

Tags: facebook, login, uwp

Estou tentando montar o login do Facebook em um aplicativo de forma que funcione utilizando o aplicativo ou o website de acordo com o tutorial:

http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/config/

Tem uma questão similar, mas que não me atende por limitar a solução apenas ao aplicativo pelo que entendi:
Utilizando Login do Facebook no Windows Phone 8.1 1

Acabei de adionar o arquivo xml com o id da minha aplicação no Facebook. Também adicionei o protocolo e coloquei este código no meu código principal:

```
        protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            base.OnActivated(args);

            // You can setup a event handler to be called back when the authentication has finished
            Session.OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished += OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished;

            var protocolArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
            LifecycleHelper.FacebookAuthenticationReceived(protocolArgs);
        }

        private void OnFacebookAuthenticationFinished(AccessTokenData session)
        {
            // here the authentication succeeded callback will be received.
            // put your login logic here
        }
```

Porém, tentando adicionar o Facebook.client não consegui e provavelmente por isso, as funções acima não estão sendo reconhecidas para que eu possa fazer o override.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar faltando? Como concluir esse objetivo?

Answer (score 1):

Na pergunta não ficou claro qual ferramenta está utilizando para comunicação com Facebook, então vou deduzir que está utilizando [facebook-csharp-sdk](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk). Outra opção interessante é [Facebook Service - UWPCommunityToolkit](http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/services/Facebook/)

Api e configuração dos aplicativos que interagem com facebook mudam constantemente, na presente data para que uma aplicação `uwp` possa utilizar login do facebook são necessárias algumas configurações:

1. Cadastrar-se como desenvolvedor na página https://developers.facebook.com/apps
2. Adicionar um aplicativo
3. Baixe o fonte aqui (para gerar o SID exigido pelo app facebook)
4. Na guia `Configurações` - `Básico`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

As únicas informações digitadas serão `Nome da Aplicação`, `Email de contato`, `SID da Windows Store (veja como pegar o SID para debug no código fonte disponível no final da resposta)`

5. Clique `+Adicionar plataforma` e escolha `Aplicativo Windows` informe o `SID da Windows Store (pode ser gerado SID para teste, veja como no fonte no final da resposta)`
6. Na opção `PRODUTOS` escolha `Login do facebook` e configure conforme imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Depois do aplicativo criado e configurações adicionadas, adicione o `Id do aplicativo`gerado pelo facebook na aplicação.

```
//somente para teste não informe diretamente no app em produção
private const string AppId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX";
```

Feito isso, seu aplicativo já será capaz de utilizar o facebook como ferramenta de login (testado com facebook api versão v2.8).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Código Fonte:
>   https://github.com/rubgithub/FacebookLogin-UWP
>
> Referências:
>   https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk
>   http://docs.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/services/Facebook/
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098187/facebook-login-windows-10-uwp-desktop
>   http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com.br/2015/06/custom-oauth-login-to-facebook-for.html